# ArrayList Index Error

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to finish up a project that uses a graphical User Interface to search through a data Base of geysers in the US. I keep getting an error for one of my Array Lists. I would include my data for the program but is is 10,000 entries long. Any help much appreciated. This is being done in BlueJ

Error :    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

DataBase Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeyserDatabase
{
private ArrayList < Geyser > Geysers;
private ArrayList < Eruption > Eruptions;

public GeyserDatabase() {

    Geysers = new ArrayList < Geyser >();
    Eruptions = new ArrayList < Eruption >();
}

public void readGeyserData(String filename){

    try{ 

        File f = new File(filename);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        String text;

        // keep reading as long as there is more data
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            text = sc.nextLine();

            Eruption e = new Eruption(text);
            Eruptions.add(e);

        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read the data file: " + filename);
    }
    createGeyserList();
}

public void addEruption (Eruption e){
    Eruptions.add(e);
}

public ArrayList <Eruption> getEruptionList(){

    return Eruptions;

}

public ArrayList <Geyser> getGeyserList(){

    return Geysers;
}

public int getNumEruptions() {
    return Eruptions.size();
}

public int getNumEruptions(int m,int d,int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for ( Eruption e : Eruptions) {
        if (e.getMonth()==m && e.getDay()==d && e.getYear()==y) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public Eruption getLateNightEruption() {
    Eruption latestEruption = Eruptions.get(0);
    int latestHour   = latestEruption.getHour();
    int latestMinute = latestEruption.getMinute();
    for ( Eruption e: Eruptions ) {
        if (e.getHour() > latestHour || (e.getHour()==latestHour && e.getMinute()>latestMinute)) {
            latestEruption = e;
            latestHour = e.getHour();
            latestMinute = e.getMinute();
        }
    }
    return latestEruption;
}

public ArrayList < Eruption > getEruptions(String geyser) {
    ArrayList < Eruption > result = new ArrayList < Eruption > ();
    for ( Eruption e: Eruptions ) {
        if (e.getGeyserName().startsWith(geyser)) {
            result.add(e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void createGeyserList(){
    ArrayList<String>nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // create temporary list of unique geyser names
    for(Eruption e:Eruptions){
        if(!nameList.contains(e.getGeyserName())){
            nameList.add(e.getGeyserName());
        }
    }

    // create a list of geysers
    ArrayList<Geyser>geyserList = new ArrayList<Geyser>();
    for(String s:nameList){
        Geyser g = new Geyser(s);

        // count number of eruptions for current geyser name
        for(Eruption e:Eruptions){
            if(e.getGeyserName().equals(g.getName()))
                g.increment();
        }
        geyserList.add(g);
    }
}

public int getMostGeysers(){

    return Geysers.size();

}

public Geyser findMostActiveGeyser(){

    Geyser MostEruptions = Geysers.get(0);
    int mostActive = MostEruptions.getNumEruptions();
    for( Geyser g : Geysers){

        if(g.getNumEruptions() > mostActive){
            MostEruptions =g;
            mostActive = g.getNumEruptions();

        }

    }
    return MostEruptions;
}

public Geyser findLeastActiveGeyser()
{

    Geyser leastActiveGeyser = Geysers.get(0);
    int leastActive = leastActiveGeyser.getNumEruptions();
    for(Geyser g: Geysers)
    {
        if(g.getNumEruptions() < leastActive)
        {
            leastActiveGeyser = g;
            leastActive = g.getNumEruptions();
        }
    }
    return leastActiveGeyser;
}

public String findDayWithMostEruptions(int y){

    int dayMost = 1;
    int monthMost = 1;
    int maxSoFar = getNumEruptions(1,1,y);
    for(int m = 1; m<=12; m++){

        for(int d = 1; d<=31;d++){
            int eruptionsDay = getNumEruptions(m,d,y);

            if(eruptionsDay>maxSoFar){
                dayMost = d;
                monthMost = m;
                maxSoFar=eruptionsDay;
            }

        }

    }
    return monthMost + "/" + dayMost + "/" + y + "Eruptions: " + maxSoFar;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    GeyserDatabase gdb = new GeyserDatabase();

    }
   }
```

GUI Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

/***********************************************************************
 * GUI front end for a Yellowstone Geyser database 
 * 
 * @author Scott Grissom
 * @version August 1, 2016

   public class GeyserGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

/** results box */
private JTextArea resultsArea;

private GeyserDatabase db;

/**JButtons */
private JButton findLateNightEruption;
private JButton findAmountOfEruptionsonDate;
private JButton findMaxEruptionsInYear;
private JButton findGeyserByName;

private JButton findMostActiveGeyser;
private JButton findLeastActiveGeyser;
private JButton getGeyserList;

private JTextField month;
private JTextField day;
private JTextField Year;
private JTextField geyser;

/** menu items */
private JMenuBar menus;
private JMenu fileMenu;
private JMenu reportsMenu;
private JMenuItem quitItem;
private JMenuItem openItem; 
private JMenuItem countItem;
private JMenuItem geyserItem;

/*********************************************************************
Main Method
 *********************************************************************/
public static void main(String arg[]){
    GeyserGUI gui = new GeyserGUI();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setTitle("Yellowstone Geysers");
    gui.pack();
    gui.setVisible(true);

}

/*********************************************************************
Constructor - instantiates and displays all of the GUI commponents
 *********************************************************************/
public GeyserGUI(){
    db = new GeyserDatabase();
    // FIX ME: the following line should be removed
    db.readGeyserData("GeyserData.txt");

    // create the Gridbag layout
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints position = new GridBagConstraints();

    // create the Results Text Area (5 x 10 cells)
    resultsArea = new JTextArea(20,40);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultsArea);
    position.gridx = 0;
    position.gridy = 0;
    position.gridheight = 10;
    position.gridwidth = 5;   
    position.insets =  new Insets(20,20,0,0);       
    add(scrollPane, position);  

    /*******************************************************/
    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);   
    position.gridx = 0;
    position.gridy = 10;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;  
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(new JLabel("Month"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 0;
    position.gridy = 11; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);  
    month = new JTextField(2);  
    add(month, position);

    /*************************************************************/
    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);   
    position.gridx = 1;
    position.gridy = 10;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;  
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(new JLabel("Day"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 1;
    position.gridy = 11; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);  
    day = new JTextField(2);  
    add(day, position);

    /**********************************************************/

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);   
    position.gridx = 2;
    position.gridy = 10;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;  
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(new JLabel("Year"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 2;
    position.gridy = 11; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);  
    Year = new JTextField(4);  
    add(Year, position);

    /**********************************************************/

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);   
    position.gridx = 3;
    position.gridy = 10;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;  
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(new JLabel("Geyser"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 3;
    position.gridy = 11; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,20,0,0);  
    geyser = new JTextField(12);  
    add(geyser, position);


    /*********************************************************/
    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(30,5,5,5);   
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 0;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1; 
    add(new JLabel("Eruptions"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 1; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5);  
    findLateNightEruption = new JButton("Late Night Eruption"); 
    findLateNightEruption.addActionListener(this);
    add(findLateNightEruption, position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 2; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5); 
    findAmountOfEruptionsonDate = new JButton("# On Date"); 
    findAmountOfEruptionsonDate.addActionListener(this);
    add(findAmountOfEruptionsonDate, position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 3; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5);  
    findMaxEruptionsInYear = new JButton("Max Eruptions in Year"); 
    findMaxEruptionsInYear.addActionListener(this);
    add(findMaxEruptionsInYear, position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 4; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5); 
    findGeyserByName = new JButton("By Name"); 
    findGeyserByName.addActionListener(this);
    add(findGeyserByName, position);


    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.insets =  new Insets(30,5,5,5);   
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 5;  
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1; 
    add(new JLabel("Geysers"), position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 6; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5); 
    findMostActiveGeyser = new JButton("Most Active");
    findMostActiveGeyser.addActionListener(this);
    add(findMostActiveGeyser, position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 7; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5); 
    findLeastActiveGeyser = new JButton("Least Active"); 
    findLeastActiveGeyser.addActionListener(this);
    add(findLeastActiveGeyser, position);

    position = new GridBagConstraints();
    position.gridx = 6;
    position.gridy = 8; 
    position.gridwidth = 1;
    position.gridheight = 1;
    position.insets =  new Insets(0,5,5,5); 
    getGeyserList = new JButton("Geyser List");  
    getGeyserList.addActionListener(this);
    add(getGeyserList, position);

    // set up File menus
    setupMenus();
    pack();

}

/*********************************************************************
List all entries given an ArrayList of eruptions.  Include a final
line with the number of eruptions listed

@param m list of eruptions
 *********************************************************************/
private void displayEruptions(ArrayList <Eruption> m){

    resultsArea.setText("");

    for(Eruption e: m){

        resultsArea.append("\n" + e.toString());

    }
    resultsArea.append ("\nNumber of Geysers: " + m.size());
}

/*********************************************************************
Respond to menu selections and button clicks

@param e the button or menu item that was selected
 *********************************************************************/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    Eruption item = null;

    // either open a file or warn the user
    if (e.getSource() == openItem){
        openFile();     
    }else if(db.getNumEruptions() == 0){
        String errorMessage = "Did you forget to open a file?";
        resultsArea.setText(errorMessage);
        return;    
    } 

    // menu item - quit
    else if (e.getSource() == quitItem){
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // FIX ME: Count menu item - display number of eruptions and geysers   
    else if (e.getSource() == countItem){
        resultsArea.setText("\nNumber of Eruptions: " + db.getNumEruptions());
    }

    // FIX ME: display late night eruption
    else if (e.getSource() == findLateNightEruption){
       resultsArea.setText("Latest Eruption\n" + db.getLateNightEruption()); 

    }

    //FIX ME: display all geyser names  
    else if (e.getSource() == getGeyserList){

        displayEruptions(db.getEruptionList());
    }

    //FIX ME: max eruptions day in a year (check for year) 
    else if(e.getSource() == findMaxEruptionsInYear){
        String aux = Year.getText(); 
        if(aux.length() == 0){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Enter a Year to Search For Maax Eruptions");

        }
        else
        {
            int y = Integer.parseInt(Year.getText());
            String result = db.findDayWithMostEruptions(y);
            resultsArea.setText(result);

        }

    }
    // FIX ME: list all eruptions for a geyser (check  for name)
    else if(e.getSource() == findGeyserByName){

        String name = geyser.getText();
        if(name.length() == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Provide Name");

        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<Eruption>result = db.getEruptions(name);
            displayEruptions(result);
        }

    }

    // FIX ME: display eruptions for a particular date
    else if(e.getSource()==findAmountOfEruptionsonDate){

         String aux1 = Year.getText();
        String aux2 = month.getText();
        String aux3 = day.getText();

        if(aux1.length() == 0 || aux2.length() == 0 || aux3.length() == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Provide year,month, and day");
        }
        else
        {
            int y = Integer.parseInt(Year.getText());
            int m = Integer.parseInt(month.getText());
            int d = Integer.parseInt(day.getText());

            int result = db.getNumEruptions(m, d, y);
            resultsArea.setText("Number of Eruptions: " + result);
        }

    }
    else if(e.getSource() == findMostActiveGeyser){
        resultsArea.setText("Most active Geyser: " + db.findMostActiveGeyser());

    }

    else if(e.getSource() == findLeastActiveGeyser){

        resultsArea.setText("Least active Geyser: " + db.findLeastActiveGeyser());

    }

}


/*********************************************************************
In response to the menu selection - open a data file
 *********************************************************************/
private void openFile(){
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

    // did the user select a file?
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
        // use the name of your lottery ticket variable 
         db.readGeyserData(filename);          
    }
}

/*********************************************************************
Create a custom gridbag constraint
 *********************************************************************/    
private GridBagConstraints makeConstraints(int x, int y, int h, int w, int align){ 
    GridBagConstraints rtn = new GridBagConstraints(); 
    rtn.gridx = x; 
    rtn.gridy = y; 
    rtn.gridheight = h; 
    rtn.gridwidth = w; 

    // set alignment: LINE_START, CENTER, LINE_END
    rtn.anchor = align; 
    return rtn; 
}   

/*********************************************************************
Set up the menu items
 *********************************************************************/
private void setupMenus(){

    // create menu components
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    openItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
    reportsMenu = new JMenu("Reports");
    countItem = new JMenuItem("Counts");

    // assign action listeners
    quitItem.addActionListener(this);
    openItem.addActionListener(this);
    countItem.addActionListener(this);

    // display menu components
    fileMenu.add(openItem);
    fileMenu.add(quitItem);
    reportsMenu.add(countItem);    
    menus = new JMenuBar();

    menus.add(fileMenu);
    menus.add(reportsMenu);
    setJMenuBar(menus);
    }         

   }
```

Geyser Code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class Geyser
{
String geyserName;
int count = 0;
public Geyser (String name){

  geyserName = name;

}

public void increment (){



    count++; 

}

public String getName() {
    return geyserName;
}

public int getNumEruptions() {
    return count;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Geyser g = new Geyser("xyz");
    if (g.getName().equals("xyz")) {
        System.out.println("getName worked well.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("getName did not work well.");
    }
    if (g.getNumEruptions() == 0) {
        System.out.println("getNumEruptions worked well.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("getNumEruptions did not work well.");
    }
    g.increment();
      if (g.getNumEruptions() == 1) {
        System.out.println("getNumEruptions worked well.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("getNumEruptions did not work well.");
     }
    }
   }
```

Eruption Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Eruption
{
int month;
int day;
int year;
int hour;
int minute;
String geyserName;

public Eruption(String info){

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(info);
    scnr.useDelimiter("/|,|:");
    month = scnr.nextInt();
    day = scnr.nextInt();
    year = scnr.nextInt();


    geyserName = scnr.next();
    hour = scnr.nextInt();

    minute = scnr.nextInt();



}

public int getMonth(){

    return month;

}

public int getDay(){

    return day;

}

public int getYear(){

    return year;
}

public int getHour(){

    return hour;

}

public int getMinute(){

    return minute;
}

public String getGeyserName(){

    return geyserName;
}

public  String toString( ){

    String geyserString = geyserName + " " + "on" + month +"/"+ day +"/" + year + "at" + hour +":"+ minute;
    return geyserString;

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Eruption e = new Eruption("1/2/2016,Old Faithful,10:46");
    if (e.getMonth() == 1) {
        System.out.println("getMonth worked well");
        }
      }


   }
```

Comment: My goodness - so muuuuuch code.

Comment: Where is this error being thrown from?

Comment: please show your stacktrace, so we can know which place you face error

Comment: When you get the error does it tell you which line it is? That would be useful :)

Comment: `Error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` usually  means that somewhere you're trying to access an empty data structure. Could you add the relevant code where this happens?

Comment: It happens at line 143 for me, so  Geyser MostEruptions = Geysers.get(0); it is in the method public Geyser findMostActiveGeyser() inside of the database code

Comment: Add empty list check into findMostActiveGeyser and findLeastActiveGeyser methods. These that I found yet cause you didnt give exact location I'm just guessing where you get exception. Please add also in which class you get exception.

Comment: I get the exception in the class GeyserDataBase and within that it is on the exact line Geyser MostEruptions = Geysers.get(0); that it throws the error.